# Using lint comments with doxygen

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen, lint, comments

For documentation, we usually have to create an additional document describing what we did when any lint messages were disabled in code `(e.g. /* lint --e228)`.
It would make it much easier to use it with `doxygen` (as we create this anyhow).

Though, I wasn't able to find any solution on how to make `doxygen` using these **lint** comments.
Did anyone try this?
Is there any solution how to use the `stric '/*lint'` but anyhow add it to `doxygen`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this Lint or PC-Lint?

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by defining a macro to expand into the lint expression comment, but making the macro expand into a different comment when expanded by `doxygen`.

The trick is to use the `-save` instruction to PC-lint<sup>TM</sup> or FlexeLint<sup>TM</sup>:

```
#ifndef LINT_CONTROL
#define LINT_CONTROL(X) /*lint -save X */ //lint X
#endif

int main () {
    int a; LINT_CONTROL(-e530)
    return a != a;
}
```

Then, in your `doxygen` configuration file, you can enable expansion of certain preprocessor macros. In particular, we can change `LINT_CONTROL` to expand into a `doxygen`-ated comment instead.

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = "LINT_CONTROL(X)=//! lint control: X"
```

Alternatively, if you have FlexeLint<sup>TM</sup>, then you can modify the shrouded source so that a doxygen comment can be used to trigger the lint control. <s>The technique is described on the [Gimpel Software Discussion Forum](http://www.gimpel.com/Discussion.cfm?ThreadID=3673)</s>. (This link seems dead, and the new discussion forum seems to no longer contain the referenced discussion any longer.)

> <sub>PC-lint and FlexeLint are trademarks of Gimpel Software.</sub>